# Javadoc not creating documentation for a class extending another class?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have made a program that consist of a few classes a class that extends however one class doesn't produce any JavaDoc or appear in the program tree. It is declared like this:

```
class myClass extends anotherClassOfMine {

}
```

Is there something special I need to add to `anotherClassOfMine` to ensure that the JavaDoc is created for `myClass`?

TIA

Comment: What do you mean "Javadoc is not created". Is there no file (page) for this class, or is it just empty? The former would be odd, the latter is to be expected when there are no Javadoc comments in your source file.

Comment: Sorry to be vague, its just not there. Not that its empty due to lack of comments. For instance the class does not appear in the JavaDoc tree view where as all the others appear fine.

Comment: Possible causes: Javadoc may be generated only for public classes? What happens if you add a Javadoc tag for the class?

Comment: I'll give this a try now, would adding the @extends tag be enough?

Comment: Pretty much anything, @author is always a good candidate. Although I must admit that I don't see why this should make a difference. The doc should be generated even if there are tags. Would be curious to know what you find.

Comment: I've added a JavaDoc comment and tag at the top, but its still not generating a file for this class.

Comment: I've just changed the deceleration of the class to public. It now produces the file.

Comment: No modfifier --> Package private --> no Javadoc? try `public class myClass extends anotherClassOfMine` See [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentiones in the comments, by default Javadoc only includes public and protected elements. Your class not being public, Javadoc thinks it is not intended to be documented.

You can either make your class public (adding `public`), or change Javadoc's behaviour by adding one of the [access options](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javadoc.html#public) `-package` or `-private`. Other values are `-public` or `-protected` (the default).

(Of course, you should also add some actual documentation, but one of the changes above should be enough so your class will show up.)